# Swipe to show Buttons in ListView just like IOS

Tags: android, listview, swipe-gesture

I am trying to achieve IOS Mail like swipe effect in Android. I have gone through several links and blogs but nothing was as good as IOS Mail app. I also searched SO but nothing was helpful.

I tried below link:

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview
https://github.com/dharanikumar/IOS_7-SwipeGesture-Android
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

This is what I want:

[image]

[image]

How can I apply these effects in Android ListView? Is there any library or some piece of code which might be helpful?

Comment: What were the problems with the libraries you tried?

Comment: There seems to be no library where a list item can have this effect on multiple sides. For example on the left side AND the right side on the same list item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what are the issues you've had with the other libraries, but you can try this one:
[AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

I'd also like to point out it's kinda futile to try to mimic a specific app of another platform in terms of look & feel.